# Logrotate: scp rotated file to different location

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have a log file, which is supposed to rotate after reaching a particular size (say 50MB). After the rotation, it should be compressed and date has to be appended to the rotated file name. Now, the rotated file must be copied to a file server.

For this, I have written a configuration which fails to work.

```
/var/log/test.log {
    compress
    missingok
    size 50M
    rotate 6
    create
    dateext
    postrotate
        rsync -avzr /var/log/test.log* REMOTE-HOST:/path/to/directory/
    endscript
}
```

When I would run `ls /var/log/test.log*` directory (on local system), I could find the rotated file `test.log-20150211.gz` and an empty file `test.log`. Where as, on REMOTE-HOST, the uncompressed version of rotated file `test.log-20150211` and the empty log file `test.log` was found.

My concern is that,

1. Why compressed log file was not transferred to the REMOTE-HOST?
2. What should be done in order to transfer ONLY the rotated file?

Edit:

I have also found that, after the logs were rotated, the service `syslog` stopped (logging process was found stopped, when check by running `tailf test.log`). The service was needed to be restarted again. Should I also add `service syslog restart` in the `postrotate` section?

Answer (score 4):

> Why compressed log file was not transferred to the REMOTE-HOST?

Compression is pretty much the last thing to happen so `postrotate` is still happening before `logrotate` has gotten that far. You can check the man page for their example of `postrotate`:

> After the log file has been rotated (but before the old version of the log has been compressed), the command `/sbin/killall -HUP syslogd` [from the postrotate script] will be executed.

You may be better off running the `rsync` as a cronjob.

> What should be done in order to transfer ONLY the rotated file?

Your `rsync` is just matching the original file name (since `*` will also match for files with no more characters) Use a more specific source name to eliminate that match:

```
rsync -avzr /var/log/test.log-* REMOTE-HOST:/path/to/directory/
```

Comment: Is there something to be done in configuration, to avoid extra overheads (like cronjobs)?

Comment: According to [this](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=429873) `lastaction` runs after compression. You may try that.

Comment: I suppose, `sharedscripts` option would not work for `lastaction`, but it does for `postrotate`. Please clarify.

Comment: Would you really need `-r`? A logfile is never a folder, or am I misunderstanding the option.

Comment: @AlexAffe I was just repeating their command, but it's possible for log files to be separated out into individual directories. In this case the file name makes it look like they're just files but ¯\_(ツ)_/¯